# Detect if we are in the index of the page (PHP)

Tags: php

I have a `header nav` with items that apply a `class` if we are in x file of the site. The problem is that I have conflict with two sections, my main `index page` (index.php) and my `Wordpress blog site` (blog/index.php). Because they have the same name of the file, **the class is added to both sections in the menu**. You can see an example here (look the menu, underline text on home and blog): https://residenciarucab.es/blog

[image]

I tried with that:

```
<?php if (basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == "index.php") echo "active";?>"
```

but how I said, it's cause conflict with index.php and blog/index.php

The functions:

```
function echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'active';
} 

function echoSelectedClassIfblog($requestUri)
{
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "blog") !== false)
        echo 'active';
}
```

Main structure:

```
<nav class="cl-effect-5">
    <li class="nav-item <?php if (basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) == "index.php") echo "active";?>" id="home-item-menu">
        <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="https://residenciarucab.es"><span data-hover="HOME">HOME</span></a>
    </li>
            </nav>
          <nav class="cl-effect-5">
    <li class="nav-item <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("rucab")?>" id="rucab-item-menu">
        <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="https://residenciarucab.es/rucab"><span data-hover="RUCAB">RUCAB</span></a>
    </li>
     </nav>
            <nav class="cl-effect-5">
    <li class="nav-item  <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("inscripciones")?>" id="inscripciones-item-menu">
        <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="https://residenciarucab.es/inscripciones"><span data-hover="INSCRIPCIONES">INSCRIPCIONES</span></a>
    </li>
     </nav>
     <nav class="cl-effect-5">
    <li class="nav-item <?=echoSelectedClassIfRequestMatches("habitaciones")?>" id="habitaciones-item-menu">
        <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="https://residenciarucab.es/habitaciones"><span data-hover="HABITACIONES">HABITACIONES</span></a>
    </li>
     </nav>
      <nav class="cl-effect-5">
    <li class="nav-item disabled" id="staff-item-menu">
       <span data-hover="STAFF">STAFF</span>
    </li>
     </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding this only to the home item, for avoiding duplicate class on home and blog, that haves the same index.php file:

```
<?php $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if($currentpage=="/" || $currentpage=="/index.php" || $currentpage=="/index" || $currentpage=="" ) { echo 'active'; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your production site, it seems to me that your structure best benefits from directory-based detection. So instead of looking at the script filename, you'll want to inspect the requested URI. An empty node would indicate the homepage, a 'blog' node would indicate the blog page, and so on.

**UPDATE**
See below for an example. This also illustrates how to write semantically correct markup for your purpose. Specifically, a `<li>` item should be a child of a `<ul>`. Also, you probably don't want to wrap every `<li>` in a `<nav>`. Use one parent `<nav>` to contain all its items.

As for detecting the currently active page, you'll have to inspect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. You could do something like this:

`$requestedUri = end(explode('/', trim($requestUri, '/')));`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .active
    {
            color: red;
    }
    .active a
    {
            color: currentColor;
    }
    a
    {
            color: black;
    }
    ul
    {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
    }
    li
    {
            display: inline-block;
    }
    li + li
    {
            padding-left: 1em;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $requestedUri = $_GET['nav_item']??'';
// For your site, you might want to do:
// $requestedUri = end(explode('/', trim($requestUri, '/')));

    $navItems =
    [
            [
                    'id' => 'home',
                    'uri' => '',
                    'name' => 'HOME'
            ],
            [
                    'id' => 'rucab',
                    'uri' => 'rucab',
                    'name' => 'RUCAB'
            ],
            [
                    'id' => 'inscripciones',
                    'uri' => 'inscripciones',
                    'name' => 'INSCRIPCIONES'
            ],
            [
                    'id' => 'habitaciones',
                    'uri' => 'habitaciones',
                    'name' => 'HABITACIONES'
            ],
            [
                    'id' => 'staff',
                    'uri' => 'staff',
                    'name' => 'STAFF'
            ],
            [
                    'id' => 'blog',
                    'uri' => 'blog',
                    'name' => 'BLOG'
            ],
            [
                    'id' => 'contacto',
                    'uri' => 'contacto',
                    'name' => 'CONTACTO'
            ]
    ];
    ?>
    <nav class="cl-effect-5">
            <ul>
    <?php foreach ($navItems as $navItem) { ?>
                    <li class="nav-item<?php echo ($requestedUri == $navItem['uri'])?' active':''; ?>" id="<?php echo $navItem['id']; ?>-item-menu">
                            <a class="nav-link menu-rucab js-scroll-trigger" href="https://residenciarucab.es/<?php echo $navItem['uri']; ?>"><span data-hover="<?php echo $navItem['name']; ?>"><?php echo $navItem['name']; ?></span></a>
                    </li>
    <?php } ?>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So how can implement that in code? I'm newbie sorry.

Comment: Sorry but no, it detect's the relative class in the DOM but all the time apply the active class to the first item of array (home): https://residenciarucab.es/habitaciones. Is there another problem, we can't do an array because one of the items (staff) have another class (disabled), because is not made yet: <li class="nav-item disabled" id="staff-item-menu">
so we can't treat all the li items by the same way...

Comment: I can't insert the new code without fixed on live site, because the users are seeing it, so I will edit my question with the html code that DOM generates and a screenshoot that's how the nav is seeing it.